# Growth of debt: exponential, logarithmic, or linear?

Tags: logarithms, terminology, exponential-function

If I have increasing debt that I don't intent to pay off for a really long time, how would I prefer to have it grow?

Exponentially, logarithmically, or linearly?

Comment: You would prefer a logarithmic growth of course, since it's the slowest. However, I doubt you would ever find a creditor to offer you such a loan

Comment: That question doesn't make much sense. The growth rate doesn't tell you anything about the amount you have to pay off. Also, a logarithmic function has an unavoidable negative tail to infinity.

Comment: This is perhaps silly.  But I too often hear "logarithmic growth" used synonymously with "exponential growth".

Comment: @YuriyS yeah I doubt that too.  Perhaps one could convince parents to give a logarithmic loan with an initial interest rate 10%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Yuriy S says, you should choose the logarithmic, since it will (eventually) be overtaken by the two others no matter how you tweak the parameters. The exponential function is by far the fastest growing of the three, and it is sadly also the one most (all) loans use. See [this question about comparing growth rates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146912/comparing-the-growth-rates).

Here are the three functions plotted, with all parameters set to $1$ (note that the differences only become more clear the bigger $x$ becomes):

[image]

Comment: Nice thanks!  Logarithmic growth is soo slow as x goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Exponentially, the fastest growing way, so that you pay the most in the end.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the graph in fact a great illustration that asymptotic results are not to be mindlessly used in finite horizon setting?

Comment: @A.S. I didn't think of it this way, but yes.